# Melhor forma de cadastrar duas chaves estrangeiras em uma tabela

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Possuo 3 tabelas, sendo elas: **pessoa_fisica**, **pesso_juridica** e **endereco**.

Tanto a tebela `pessoa_fisica`, quanto a tebela `pessoa_juridica` usam a tabela `endereco`. Gostaria de adicionar duas chaves estrangeiras na tabela `endereço`. Sendo uma vinculada ao `id` de `pessoa_fisica` e outra ao `id` de `pessoa_juridica`. Assim, caso um registro de `pessoa_fisica` ou `pessoa_juridica` seja excluído, o endereço também será.

O meu problema é que o MySQL não permite que eu cadastre um registro na tabela endereco se não existir a referencia das chaves estrangeiras nas tabelas `pessoa_fisica` e `pessoa_juridica`.

Existe alguma forma de tratar isso sem que seja necessário criar duas tabelas de endereco (sendo uma para `pessoa_fisica` e outra para `pessoa_juridica`)?

Comment: @Marconi existem informações diferentes em pessoa_fisica e pessoa_juridica. Por isso, essa opção não é viavel para mim.

Comment: Eu gostaria de conseguir uma opção em que não fosse necessário a criação de duas tabelas de endereço. Pq os campos de endereço são iguais para as duas tabelas. Então não sei se duplicar essa tabela seria a melhor opção!

Comment: Achei interessante sua dúvida, aqui tem um ótimo passo de como modelar suas tabelas. [Modelagem de Dados – Parte 06 (Generalizações / Especializações)](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/6167/banco-de-dados/modelagem-de-dados-parte-06-generalizacoes-especializacoes?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Comment: @alan, existe sim, o que você pode fazer e adicionar as chaves estrangeiras de maneira que as duas possam ser opcionais. irei postar um exemplo de como criar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que criar na tabela 2 chaves estrangeiras podendo elas serem nulas,
Exemplo do create das tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum.pessoa_fisica (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  cpf VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum.pessoa_juridica (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  razao_social VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  cnpj VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB; 



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum.endereco (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_pessoa_juridica INT NULL,
  id_pessoa_fisica INT NULL,
  rua VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  numero VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_endereco_pessoa_juridica_idx (id_pessoa_juridica ASC),
  INDEX fk_endereco_pessoa_fisica1_idx (id_pessoa_fisica ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_endereco_pessoa_juridica
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa_juridica)
    REFERENCES forum.pessoa_juridica (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_endereco_pessoa_fisica1
    FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa_fisica)
    REFERENCES forum.pessoa_fisica (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Aqui irei inserir nas tabelas 1 dado fake para cada tabela

```
INSERT INTO pessoa_fisica(nome, cpf)VALUES('PessoaFisica', '00000000000');
INSERT INTO pessoa_juridica(razao_social, cnpj)VALUES('PessoaJuridica', '000000000000000');
INSERT INTO endereco(id_pessoa_fisica, rua, numero) VALUES(1,'Rua Pessoa Física', '1');
INSERT INTO endereco(id_pessoa_juridica, rua, numero) VALUES(1,'Rua Pessoa Juridica', '2');
```

Para consultar os endereços das pessoas fisicas e juridicas usamos as seguintes querys:

```
/** CONSULTA ENDERECO PESSOA FISICA ID 1*/
SELECT
    pf.nome,
    pf.cpf,
    e.rua,
    e.numero
FROM pessoa_fisica pf
LEFT JOIN endereco e
ON e.id_pessoa_fisica = pf.id
WHERE pf.id = 1;


/** CONSULTA ENDERECO PESSOA JURIDICA ID 1*/
SELECT
    pj.razao_social,
    pj.cnpj,
    e.rua,
    e.numero
FROM pessoa_juridica pj
LEFT JOIN endereco e
ON e.id_pessoa_fisica = pj.id
WHERE pj.id = 1;
```

Porém não é a melhor forma de modelagem, as tabelas pessoas_fisicas e pessoas_juridicas deveriam ser apenas 1 tabela onde existiriam referencia com tipo pessoa porque tem muitas colunas que podem ser iguais, e caso existisse algo a mais em alguma tabela, você criaria outras tabelas com essas informações, mas isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: O meu problema foi exatamente esse ao tentar fazer desta forma que você apresentou. Ao criar duas chaves estrangeiras na tabela endereco com CASCADE. Elas são criadas sem problema nenhum. Porém, quando você cadastrar uma pessoa fisica e for tentar cadastrar o seu endereço, o MySQL retornará um erro. Porque não existe referência de pessoa_júridica cadastrada. Essa foi a forma inicial que tentei utilizar e não deu certo para mim. Eu consegue resolver o problema seguido o modelo apresentado no link q o @Marconi passou. Mas ainda n tive tempo de adicionar a resposta aqui.

Comment: Dessa maneira que postei não irá dar erro pois os campos podem ser nulos, se quiser executar o exemplo, verá que não tem erro. Abç

Comment: Mas o problema n está nos campos. Quando você adiciona uma chave estrangeira a uma tabela. Você só pode cadastrar um registro nessa tabela caso exista pelo menos 1 registro cadastrado na tabela em que a chave estrangeira faz referencia. No meu caso, ao cadastrar uma pessoa_fisica eu não tenho nenhum registro cadastrado em pessoa_juridica e quando eu tento cadastrar o endereço ele não permite por n existir nenhum registro cadastrado em pessoa_juridica.

Comment: Você não está entendendo o ponto, vamos lá, temos 3 tabelas pessoa_fisica, pessoa_juridica e endereco(onde possui duas chaves, id_pessoa_fisica e id_pessoa_juridica) DUAS CHAVES DISTINTAS PODENDO SER NULL, sendo assim quando eu criar uma pessoa física essa receberá um id, e quando eu for cadastrar o endereço passarei esse ID para a tabela endereço no campo id_pessoa_fisica, caso eu faça uma juridica irá para o campo id_pessoa_juridica AS CHAVES ESTRANGEIRAS PODEM SER NULL, nesse caso quando for fisica, juridica ficara null e vice e versa.

Comment: Caso tenha dúvidas crie um banco de dados teste e execute os comandos acima para melhor compreensão

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e vc está certo. Eu acabei separando de outra forma criando uma quarta tabela pessoa o que deixou um pouco mais organizado algumas informações duplicadas entre pessoa_fisica e pessoa_juridica. Mas a forma que vc fez também resolve o problema! value! ;)

Comment: Edite sua resposta para q eu possa votar nela!

Comment: Editei, e sim, até deixei uma observação no final, que as vezes é mais viável criar uma tabela a mais, mas para o seu problema esse modelo resolve